# How to connect my Android App to a sql server DB(sql server 2008)

Tags: sql-server, database, jdbc

I have connected my sql sever DB in Database Development and I am able to ping and get a respond , but my code to connect to the db from my app for data retrieval and storage purposes  keep getting the same error message.

Here is my code:

```
package com.first.mainapp;

import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;

import com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement;
import com.mysql.jdbc.Statement;


public class Connect {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        java.sql.Connection conn = null;

        String dbName = "People_12";
        String serverip="192.168.0.1";
        String serverport="1433";

        String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://"+serverip+"\\SQLEXPRESS:"+serverport+";databaseName="+dbName+"";

     Statement stmt = null;
        ResultSet result = null;

        String driver = "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver";

        String databaseUserName = "sa";
        String databasePassword = "1234";

        try {

            Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, databaseUserName, databasePassword);
            stmt = (Statement) conn.createStatement();

            result = null;
            String pa,us;

            result = stmt.executeQuery("select * from User_Table ");

            while (result.next()) {

                us=result.getString("uname");
                pa = result.getString("pass");              
                System.out.println(us+"  "+pa);
            }

            conn.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my error message:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement cannot be cast to com.mysql.jdbc.Statement
    at com.first.mainapp.Connect.main(Connect.java:35)
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the error is in your imports. In this [example](http://www.java-tips.org/other-api-tips/jdbc/how-to-connect-microsoft-sql-server-using-jdbc.html) they use `import java.sql.*;` (specifically, java.sql.Statement should be the import you need for the Statement type). When you use `import com.mysql.jdbc.Statement;`, you will get the wrong Statement type (for mysql).